# MYSQL Stored procedure, approvals and approvers

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Im kinda new reading stored procedure.

I was thinking if this is posible to do in store procedure in mysql.

I have sequence of approval process called step. approved column; 1 is yes 0 is no.

Basically I have Step 1 to 3..in my approval sequence.
if step 1 approved status is 0 he will be the first to approved or see the table.
if step 1 approve is 1. step 2 can now see the table.

Transaction Steps Table:

```
id  transaction_id  approver_id step    approved
1   1               1           1       1
2   1               2           2       0
3   1               3           3       0

4   2               3           1       1
5   2               1           2       1
6   2               2           3       0

7   3               2           1       0
8   3               3           2       0
9   3               1           3       0

10  4               1           1       1
11  4               3           2       0
12  4               2           3       0
```

Example If my Approval id = 2

In My View:I can only see all those next in que approvals

```
id  transaction_id  approver_id step    approved
2   1               2           2       0
6   2               2           3       0
7   3               2           1       0
```

pls let me know if this is possible. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want rows that are the first non-approved for each transaction *and* the approver is 2.

Try this:

```
select ts.*
from transactionsteps ts join
     (select transaction_id, min(step) as minstep
      from transactionsteps
      where approved = 0
      group by transaction_id
     ) t
     on ts.transaction_id = t.transaction_id and
        ts.step = t.minstep
where approver_id = 2;
```

Comment: Holly sick haha this is good.. awesome.. I thought I need to do it on Stored Procedure but its not..